# javascript executing both if else blocks

Tags: javascript, html

my Javascript function is executing both if else blocks.
I want to add checkbox value in array if it is checked and remove value if its unchecked.

**The output is inside if and inside else. But i want to run either if or else block.**

**Edit**: I am generating dynamic label tags using php. I just shown one label tag in this example for understanding. But value of each input tag is assgined from database and is wrapped in label tag.

```js
function filterbyprotype(current) {
  protypes = [];

  document.querySelectorAll('.filterprotypes').forEach(function(ele) {
    console.log(ele);
    if (ele.checked) {
      current.closest('label').style.background = "var(--headercolor)";
      current.closest('label').style.color = "#fff";


      protypes.push(ele.value);
      alert("inside if");

    } else {
      current.closest('label').style.background = "transparent";
      current.closest('label').style.color = "#000";


      delete protypes[ele.value];
      alert("inside else");

    }

  });

}
```

```html
<label style="padding: 6px 15px;border: 1px solid grey;border-radius: 10px;margin-right: 16px;cursor: pointer;text-transform: capitalize;">
    <b><?=$filter_protype['protype']?></b>
    <input class="filterprotypes" type="checkbox" name="filter-protype[]" value="<?=$filter_protype['protype']?>" onchange="filterbyprotype(this)">
</label>
```

Comment: That really doesn't sound possible and you are likely misinterpreting the problem. Please provide a runnable [mre] that demonstrates the issue. You can click on `<>` in question editor to make it runnable here in the page

Comment: I've edited your post and created snippet from your code. Your provided code works as expected.

Comment: my outputs is "inside if" and then "inside else"

Comment: Code works fine now after editing by @ulou

Comment: Those alerts would be for different elements, not for the same one

Comment: You have a foreach loop - do you have 2 checkboxes where one is checked one not?

Comment: And that demo only does one alert each time you change the checkbox and works correctly

Comment: There was hidden element right most on the right in html. I believe it's injected by php and it's exactly same input, so there are 2 same inputs. Logic is inside `forEach` so it's always called twice, that's why he see 2 alerts. Also the tag php wasn't added, I just did it.

Comment: @ulou PHP isn't really relevant to this js problem

Comment: @charlietfl In case that he provides, it is, otherwise its just 1 input and everything works as expected, but I agree that under the hood, this is fully js problem.

Comment: @ulou I removed the php tag. You only use tags that are relevant to the specific problem. How the html is generated is not relevant here. Doesn't matter if it was generated by ruby, java , python etc. An SME in php is wasting time visiting this issue

Comment: Could it be that you mix up current and ele? See https://codepen.io/codemuggle/pen/WNppZMe and test if that matches what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just shown one label tag in this example for understanding

That was very unlucky, cause problem with your solution occurring only when there is more than 1 input element.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.filterprotypes').forEach(function(ele) { ... }
```

This line is problematic, cause logic inside it is triggered on all inputs every time you click any of them. Additionally this iteration is not needed at all, cause you already passing element to function (`current`).

Working solution after changes:

```js
function filterbyprotype(current) {
  protypes = [];
  if (current.checked) {
    current.closest('label').style.background = "var(--headercolor)";
    current.closest('label').style.color = "#fff";
    protypes.push(current.value);
    alert("inside if");
  } else {
    current.closest('label').style.background = "transparent";
    current.closest('label').style.color = "#000";
    delete protypes[current.value];
    alert("inside else");
  }
}
```

```html
<label style="padding: 6px 15px;border: 1px solid grey;border-radius: 10px;margin-right: 16px;cursor: pointer;text-transform: capitalize;">
    <b><?=$filter_protype['protype']?></b>
    <input class="filterprotypes" type="checkbox" name="filter-protype[]" value="<?=$filter_protype['protype']?>" onchange="filterbyprotype(this)">
</label>
<label style="padding: 6px 15px;border: 1px solid grey;border-radius: 10px;margin-right: 16px;cursor: pointer;text-transform: capitalize;">
    <b><?=$filter_protype['protype']?></b>
    <input class="filterprotypes" type="checkbox" name="filter-protype[]" value="<?=$filter_protype['protype']?>" onchange="filterbyprotype(this)">
</label>
```